# Return async task using LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I want to implement function that return list of child items from database asynchronously. So I write a function:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetFiles(int parentId)
    {
        var data = from file in DB.Files
                   where file.ParentId == parentId
                   select new { name = file.Name, id = file.Id };
        return data;
    }
```

However I can see a warning: Async method lasks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. How to rewrite this function into asynchronous?

Comment: Just a side note to say that you're approach the problem from the wrong direction. You should never "make a method async" and *then* figure out how to do it. Instead, consider all the I/O of your app, make them use `await`, and *then* let it grow from there. In other words, use something like `ToListAsync` *before* you mark the method `async`.

Comment: Since the only purpose of my method is to get some data from database it should be async from the start

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your can use `ToListAsync()`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220258(v=vs.113).aspx

```
var data = await DB.Files
    .Where(file => file.ParentId == parentId)
    .Select
        (
            new 
            { 
                name = file.Name,
                id = file.Id 
            }
        ).ToListAsync();
return data;
```

Alternatively:

```
var data = from file in DB.Files
           where file.ParentId == parentId
           select new { name = file.Name, id = file.Id };
return await data.ToListAsync();
```

Be aware that this will query the data. Also, you may reconsider your method name. When a method is async the [naming convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#BKMK_NamingConvention) suggest that you append "Async" to your method name.

> By convention, you append "Async" to the names of methods that have an
>   Async or async modifier.

Answer (score 6):

[ToListAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads) method is not working with enumarable anymore. You can use [FromResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8) method  like below :

```
var data = from file in DB.Files
           where file.ParentId == parentId
           select new { name = file.Name, id = file.Id };
    return await Task.FromResult(data);
```

Comment: Your answer makes no sense, since as per your linked document about ToListAsync it returns a Task<List> and List-class implements IEnumerable. So yes the return value of ToListAsync is enumerable.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively you could use, `TaskCompletionSource` -

```
public static async Task<string> ReturnAsync()
{
    var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    tsc.SetResult("hello world");
    return await tsc.Task;
}
```